# Nextcloud Kubernetes deployment Internal server error

Tags: kubernetes, nextcloud, kubernetes-deployment

I want to install nextcloud in kubernetes according to this guide: https://www.codementor.io/@alicheaito/deploying-nextcloud-on-kubernetes-with-kustomize-tn78vcz0a

I don't use any ingress. For testing I used RunAsUser: 0 at the deployment, I know this is not secure, and I will change it to port 8080 and user id 1099 in production. When I call the page I get this screen:
[image: Internal server error]

I don't see anything suspecting in the logs:
[image]

I am new to kubernetes, and I don't know where to begin to debug.

My deployment.yaml for nextcloud:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    component: app
  name: app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: app
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: app
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1099
        runAsUser: 33
        runAsGroup: 1099
      containers:
        - image: nextcloud:apache
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: app
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: MYSQL_DATABASE
                  name: db-secrets
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
                  name: db-secrets
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: MYSQL_USER
                  name: db-secrets
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/www/html
              name: app-persistent-storage
            - mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
              name: app-persistent-storage
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: app-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: app-pvc
```

The service.yaml for nextcloud:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    component: app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    component: app
```

Screenshots from services and  pods:
[image: kubectl get svc]
[image]

Here is the nextcloud.log file there is something suspicious, but that didn't help me:

```
{"reqId":"4cSKDj718CckiPwauoRU","level":3,"time":"2020-05-28T11:00:55+00:00","remoteAddr":"10.20.0.8","user":"--","app":"base","method":"GET","url":"/","message":{"Exception":"Exception","Message":"Failed to start session","Code":0,"Trace":[{"file":"/var/www/html/lib/base.php","line":429,"function":"__construct","class":"OC\\Session\\Internal","type":"->","args":["oci0uf3awll8"]},{"file":"/var/www/html/lib/base.php","line":647,"function":"initSession","class":"OC","type":"::","args":[]},{"file":"/var/www/html/lib/base.php","line":1089,"function":"init","class":"OC","type":"::","args":[]},{"file":"/var/www/html/index.php","line":36,"args":["/var/www/html/lib/base.php"],"function":"require_once"}],"File":"/var/www/html/lib/private/Session/Internal.php","Line":65,"CustomMessage":"--"},"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36","version":""}
{"reqId":"4cSKDj718CckiPwauoRU","level":3,"time":"2020-05-28T11:00:56+00:00","remoteAddr":"10.20.0.8","user":"--","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"/","message":"You are using a fallback implementation of the intl extension. Installing the native one is highly recommended instead. at /var/www/html/3rdparty/patchwork/utf8/src/Patchwork/Utf8/Bootup/intl.php#18","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36","version":""}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question the way it does not have images of logs but the texts instead? It's hard for us to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me address the "I don't know where to begin to debug" part of your question as I am sure that it would be the most beneficial approach for you in the long-run.

There are two most common things to debug which also applies in your use-case:

[Debug Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/) by checking:

- Does the Service exist?
- Does the Service work by DNS name?
- Does the Service work by IP?
- Is the Service defined correctly?
- Does the Service have any Endpoints?
- Is the kube-proxy working?

[Debug Running Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/) which explains how to debug Pods running (or crashing) on a Node by:

- Examining pod logs
- Debugging with container exec
- Debugging with an ephemeral debug container
- Debugging via a shell on the node

I also recommend going through the [Troubleshoot Applications](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/) guide:

> This guide is to help users debug applications that are deployed into
>   Kubernetes and not behaving correctly.

Steps and details can be found in the linked sources.

Knowing the above methods will help you understand where and what to check in the first place from the Kubernetes side. I hope you'll find it useful.